# Date Validation in Javascript on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have coded an HTML form which is linked to JavaScript to check whether the entered date in after the current date. The program works properly on Microsoft Edge and Edge Insider but isn't returning any value in Google Chrome

```
function validation()
{
  var cnt=0;
  var datecnt=0;

  //Name Validation
  var n = document.forms["reservationForm"]["name"].value;
  if (n !="")
  {cnt++;}

//Mobile Number Validation
var m = document.forms["reservationForm"]["tel"].value;
var IndNum = /^[0]?[789]\d{9}$/;
if(IndNum.test(m))
{
   cnt++;
}
//Email Address Validation
if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(reservationForm.email.value))
  {cnt++;}

//Number of Guests Validation
var g = document.forms["reservationForm"]["number"].value;
if(g>0 && g<=15)
  {cnt++;}

// Date Validation
var GivenDate = document.forms["reservationForm"]["Date"].value;
var CurrentDate = new Date();
GivenDate = new Date(GivenDate);

if(GivenDate > CurrentDate)
{cnt++;datecnt++}

  //Final Dialog Box Check
  if(cnt==5)
  {alert("Reservation Confirmed");}

  if(datecnt==0)
  {alert("Please enter a date before the current date.");
    return (false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to JavaScript; however, putting `<script src="js/stack.js"></script>` in a `<body>` of an HTML file and opening the latter in a browser (not Chrome) gives me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement` on the `return (false);` line.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you set this up as a usable demo at jsfiddle.net ? PS @EnricoMariaDeAngelis has probably given you the clue you need already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249316/uncaught-syntaxerror-illegal-return-statement)

Comment: What is the actual code? Seems like you cut the middle of it out and pasted it here

Answer (score 2):

You actually have multiple things that are not quite correct...

The first one and probably most important is the keyword `return` in JavaScript, which is not permitted outside a function.

The second one: you have too many parenthesis. The last `}` is not necessary.

The third one: If you want the givenDate to be AFTER the current date, you have to modify your alert as it says the contrary. If you want the givenDate to be BEFORE the current date, you should check as follows: `if (GivenDate < CurrentDate){ ...`

Hope this helps

**[EDIT]**
Ok I didn't see, that some of my points were pointed out in the comments ;)

Comment: The last parenthesis was for closing the main function. I copied only part of the function in the box above so added the '{' by mistake. The Date entered by users should be after the current date, so in that case: ```if (GivenDate > CurrentDate)``` should be correct. The ```return``` is part of a function called validation() which opens at the top. If you want, I can mail you the whole program. Also, this works on Microsoft Edge but is facing problem only on Google Chrome.

Comment: ok i see... why don‘t you edit your initial post and add the whole function? or even better, the whole form with the validation function? this might help all of us understanding what‘s going on there. (it cannot be that it works on edge!!! and not on chrome. - i‘m joking  )