# __V8_EXCEPTION: Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

Tags: javascript

I am using a CEF3 based browser.

It supports adding / evaluating code without having to define a function.

I also don't have to state

```
"<script type = "text/javascript">
```

etc.

Instead, I can just pass a string to like this:

```
 Me.webkitx1.Eval(somestring)
```

It works fine.

Here is a code that I use to show the focus in the first found input element when the page has loaded.

Because "element" may also be null / empty / nothing, I have tried adding "return;" in one line.
However, since I do not define a function, it doesn't allow me to use "return;", I guess...

What could I do instead?

I would like to avoid using a bigger if-then-clause.

Thank you!

```
var element = document.querySelector("*[autofocus]");
if (element)
{
}
else
{
   element = document.querySelector("form input:not([type=hidden])");
}

if (element)
{
}
else
{
  return; // not working. The error is: "__V8_EXCEPTION:Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"
}

element.selectionStart = element.selectionEnd = element.value.length;
element.focus();
var y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
window.scroll(
{
   top: y,
   behavior: "smooth"
});
```

Comment: Instead of putting a `return` in the `else` part, just move all the conditional code inside the `if` block?!

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that does work. I wanted to avoid that and wanted to know if there is any other solution, but yes... using a big if-then-clause does work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249316/uncaught-syntaxerror-illegal-return-statement)
This exception means the return statement is outside of a function. It does nothing with CEF. this is illegal in JavaScript. You should move the entire code into a lambda, if you want to avoid moving the code into a conditional block. There is a lot articles about this Illegal return statement on the Internet and StackOverflow.